# How to access a website that is htaccess password secure through JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

Is it possible to access a website that is `htaccess` (Username&password) secured through JMeter?

I am getting authorization error. I am giving username and password with HTTP request but still getting this error. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done via : `Thread Group -> Add -> Config Element -> HTTP Authorization Manager`
Add the following configuration:

```
Base URL: https://mydomain.com/WebServices/
Username: basicblazeuser_wrong
Password: basicblazepass_wrong,
```

for more info checkout [this URL.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-wsdl-authentication-with-jmeter)